# Permanently disable guest account in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user-accounts, guest-account

If I leave my PC unlocked for 30 seconds, my son enables the guest account, so he can use my PC when I'm away. The obvious solution is to teach him not to do it, but he's autistic and hard to manage, so a technical solution would be best.

Is there a way to delete the guest account or disable it in the registry or to guard the setting with a password like in Linux?

Please, no judgemental parenting advice.

Comment: My advice would be to switch to a standard account instead of an administrator account, so the guest account can't be enabled without a password. If not you could disable Control Panel if you don't use it much. Or http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/deleting-guest-account/5a116d33-0056-47ca-b51a-b6615b90e160 .

Comment: @RsyaStudios nailed it, stop using an administrator account if you're going to leave it unattended in a hostile environment. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this if @zoredache's solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rsya_Studios had the right solution.

> My advice would be to switch to a standard account instead of an administrator account, so the guest account can't be enabled without a password.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/

This made my life easier. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As the comments mentioned the best method is to simply never let the opportunity exist to to make the change.

But you could use the Deny log on locally policy.

[image: deny local login]

Comment: It already looked like this when I tried. I could still enable the guest account and it still was able to login. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It sure seems like that should be denying local logins.  I haven't actually tested this policy it with the guest account, or at all on Win8.1.